# In eclipse CDT, is there a way to find the loop statement associated with a break (or continue) statement?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have some "complicated" C code that has multiple nested for and while loops as well as nested if statements. Within the loops, there are break statements buried down in if statements. Can eclipse show me which loop the break (or continue) statement is going to act on? Like a hotkey, F3 for example.

Comment: Using Eclipse to format the code will put the *break* or *continue* statements one level deeper than the associated *while* or *for*.  You can also refactor out procedural code to make the looping code easier to see.

Comment: Yes, hitting F3 (or Ctrl+clicking) on `continue` or `break` jumps to the location where the program would continue in this case (`continue` to the beginning of the loop to continue; `break` to the end of the loop).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I guess this is about `continue`/`break` with labels .

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Not always. I have a break within several nested if statements. Indentation will not solve it.

Comment: @howlger F3 does not do it for me. I've tried with eclipse 2019, 2020, and the Xilinx SDK version. Curious if you have some setting I don't know about. Also no labels.

Comment: It works for me in the Java editor. If your question is about C/C++, you should say so and tag the question with [eclipse-cdt], not with [eclipse].

Comment: @howlger smh. You are right. I didn’t indicate the language at all! Thank you.